# Motion 4.0 Server working but not streaming

Tags: camera, motion, streaming

I'm playing around with Motion 4.0 on my P3+
I seem to have everything working OK, its detecting motion and recording pictures and video.
but when I go to the web page for the streaming output all I get is:

```
Motion 4.0 Running [1] Cameras
All
```

no video feed. It's the same regardless of which browser I use and from which computer I do it from.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Oh. its the Raspberry Pi camera, not a USB camera. BCM module is loaded on boot.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it.
I had the streaming port and the HTTP control on the same port.
I changed the control port to 8082 and then I could see the live stream on 8081