# Motion terminating immediately

Tags: raspicam, motion

I have set up my Raspberry Pi 3 model B v2 and the Raspberry Pi camera module 2.1.

The camera works, I can take pictures with `raspistill` and access them via SSH. Querying the camera properties with `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --all` works.

I installed and configured `motion` to not only work on localhost. After starting `motion`, shutdown and power-cycled, I can neither access the website with the video on port 8081 nor the config website on port 8080.

When starting or restarting the service, I get the following in the motion log:

```
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] motion_startup: Motion 4.3.2 Started
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] motion_startup: Using default log type (ALL)
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] motion_startup: Using log type (ALL) log level (NTC)
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] become_daemon: Motion going to daemon mode
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] motion_startup: Motion running as daemon process
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Feb 26 20:18:28] webu_start_strm: Starting all camera streams on port 8081
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Feb 26 20:18:28] webu_strm_ntc: Started camera 0 stream on port 8081
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Feb 26 20:18:28] webu_start_ctrl: Starting webcontrol on port 8080
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Feb 26 20:18:28] webu_start_ctrl: Started webcontrol on port 8080
[0:motion] [NTC] [ENC] [Feb 26 20:18:28] ffmpeg_global_init: ffmpeg libavcodec version 58.91.100 libavformat version 58.45.100
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] translate_init: Language: English
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 Camera Name: (null) Device: /dev/video0
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] main: Waiting for threads to finish, pid: 3107
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] motion_init: Camera 0 started: motion detection Enabled
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] vid_start: Opening V4L2 device
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_device_open: Using videodevice /dev/video0 and input -1
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_device_capability: - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_device_capability: - VIDEO_OVERLAY
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_device_capability: - READWRITE
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_device_capability: - STREAMING
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_input_select: Name = "Camera 0"- CAMERA
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_norm_select: Device does not support specifying PAL/NTSC norm
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_pixfmt_set: Testing palette YU12 (640x480)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_pixfmt_set: Using palette YU12 (640x480)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 4 items
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] mlp_actions: End of event 1
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:28] motion_loop: Thread exiting
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] vid_close: Cleaning up V4L2 device
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Feb 26 20:18:28] v4l2_cleanup: Closing video device /dev/video0
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:29] main: Threads finished
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:29] main: Motion terminating
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Feb 26 20:18:29] motion_remove_pid: Closing logfile (/home/motion/log/motion.log).
```

As you can see, it started in daemon mode and started streaming. But from the last lines, it exits and closes the camera. After that, the `motion` service is no longer running and consequently the website is unreachable.

```bsh
$ ps -ef | grep motion
pi        3360  1210  0 20:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto motion
```

What's wrong here and what do I need to do in order to watch the video stream in the browser?

Questions that I have already reviewed:

- [Can't access motion server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29259/cant-access-motion-server), but my localhost settings are already turned off (`daemon on`, `setup_mode off`, `webcontrol_localhost off`, `stream_localhost off`)
- [Motion 4.0 Server working but not streaming](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76866/motion-4-0-server-working-but-not-streaming): my ports are `webcontrol_port 8080` and `stream_port 8081`.
- [Motion exiting without any error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133722/motion-exiting-without-any-error-usb-web-camera) looks similar but has no answer

If I run motion directly with `sudo motion`, it works. Using `sudo service motion start`, it doesn't.

Comment: See here https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/pull/303

Comment: @Andy: that pull request was merged in 2017. Why does it still affect me in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

Found this: The `systemd` service file, with `Type=simple`, expects motion to run in non-daemon mode, and not fork. If daemon on is set in `motion.conf`, the service will fail to run.

Comment: Thanks to MatsK and Wouter. Your answers are the only reference to setting 'daemon=off' to get motion to run under systemd. Kudos. No one else ever mentioned this in all the answers I have read. Again I was foiled by tribal knowledge that should have been added to motion.conf a long time ago.